# UIView flip vertically

Tags: xcode, uiview, rotation, flip, catransform3d

I know it's probably a dummy question, but I have to ask: How to flip a `UIView` vertically? I'm not asking for doing a animation, but just flip it.

I can do vertical flip a `UILabel` by:

`label1.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`

and turn it back by:

```
label1.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

But when I'm doing it to a view:

```
self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

I think it only rotate half way... So, any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 55):

I realize this is an old question, but I'll leave this here anyway. The following would flip the view vertically using just the y-scale of the layer, so it would be my preference:

```
self.view.layer.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Comment: I see you miss the code, if self is kind of UIView, you can use

`self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)`

if you want to use layer.transform, it is kind of CATransform3D, so the code is

`self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1)`